# STS4 How to run Code Coverage in Spring Tools Suite 4?

Tags: spring-boot, code-coverage, spring-tool-suite

I am unable to find a way how to run code coverage in STS4.

In Eclipse Oxygen, I needed to do:

1. Right-click on project > Properties > Coverage to enable code
   coverage
2. Then, right-click on project > Run Code Coverage

However, both of these 2 options are missing in STS4

Comment: There is no code coverage feature installed by default in the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution (and never was, as far as I remember), but you might have had an Eclipse installation with such a third-party plugin installed. Maybe installing this from the marketplace helps: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclemma-java-code-coverage

Comment: @MartinLippert. Thank you.  That worked.  Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear that, posted as answer again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no code coverage feature installed by default in the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution (and never was, as far as I remember), but you might have had an Eclipse installation with such a third-party plugin installed. Maybe installing this from the marketplace helps:

marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclemma-java-code-coverage

Comment: Search for  "EclEmma Java Code Coverage" in Eclipse marketplace

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, if you don't find the tool "EclEmma Java Code Coverage" in Eclipse Marketplace, search it through the other setup menu : Help > Install New Software...

Installation's official guide: https://www.eclemma.org/installation.html.